# WCF Restful service - image not showing

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest, wcf-rest

I have an restful webservice (WCF Rest service termplate 4.0 C# - VS 2010). The service runs very good, but if I want to show an image in the browser, which is in root directory of webservices, I see nothing...

If the project running on localhost, its allright...

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the traffic between the browser and the service?  Something like Fiddler is very useful for this.

Are you trying to pass a reference to the image or returning it in the response with the ContentType of the response set to "image/jpeg".

Answer (score 0):

Set Content-type: image/jpeg for your response and ensure that your response contains any binary data. But to say more, provide more details